# Generating a gitlab ssh key from windows

Tags: ssh, cmd, gitlab

I've tried following [this guide](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README) on generating an ssh key in order to use gitlab.

Before I know if I should generate a key I must check if there is one already like this:

```
type %userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

If it says this, then I must generate the key:

```
the system cannot find the path specified
```

What is the next step? Because the guide doesn't say anything in case this is the message I get.

Edit: I've tried

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@example.com"
```

And I get

```
'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Edit 2: I am on windows.

Comment: Try this one `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@example.com"`

Comment: @sajibkhan I added an edit for this command

Comment: Judging by the paths in the OP's commands and the error messages coming from the shell, I'm betting the OP is on windows. `ssh-keygen` is a commonly a *nix tool.

Comment: Make sure you've installed `git` first. Then try `ssh-keygen ...`

Comment: `ssh-keygen` isn't part of `git`.

Comment: `type "%userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub"`; `type` does nothing but displaying the content of a text file in the console window; the message simply means there is no such file...

Comment: hey @Hadarsi320 do you ever accept answers?

Comment: @WarrenP hey what's up dude? Dorry I didn't except your answer, but I guess better late than never.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

ON windows if you have git for windows installed, run `git-gui`. Then click Help then click Show Ssh Key, then click Generate Key.

While you're at it, then copy to the clipboard, and then go to your Gitlab account page and add the SSH key to your Gitlab account's ssh settings.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I tried for ages to get it working with Puttygen, but that gave me the wrong kind of key apparently.

Comment: Gosh, this makes me mad how simple that was. Thanks.

Comment: simple enough, I think suffering is for Linux!

Answer (score 1):

The intention here is for `%userprofile%` to be an environment variable present in your system that contains your actual user's home directory. Either check why this environment variable isn't set on your system and fix it, or for a quick fix, replace `%userprofile%` in the above command with your actual user's home directory.

Comment: Replacing it as in instead of writing `%userprofile%` writing `C:\Users\example`?

Comment: @Hadarsi320 Yes, assuming `example` is your username.

Comment: The person is actually thinking that a type command will generate something. No. If it existed already, it would make it be displayed to the screen.  But the type command in dos is like the cat command in unix, it just reads from one place and puts the output in another place, like the console (screen).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go along with creating the key in windows without relying on git, you can go to `Apps & Features > Optional Features > OpenSSH client (install)`.

Once that is done the keygen command will be available to you. Please note that one needs to specify the bits (-b) as the default size will not be accepted by gitlab.

Will look like this: `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -C "email@example.com"`